# Splice array on click - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, array-splice

I have a type of newsfeed wall like Facebook were you can create posts. I want when I click on the glyphicon in my post to remove that certain post.

The code is:

```
function loadPosts(){
    $('#allPosts').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < aPosts.length; i++){
        var postData = aPosts[i];
        var comments ="";
        for (var j = 0; j < postData.comments.length; j++ )
        {
            comments += '<p class="myComment">' + postData.comments[j].from + '<strong>says: </strong>'+ postData.comments[j].text +'</p>';
        }
        $('#allPosts').prepend('<div data-postId="'+i+'"class="wrapPost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'  +
            postData.from +' '+''  +
            '<strong>wrote :</strong>'+
            '<li>' + postData.text + '</li>' + comments +
            '<input type=text class=commentBox placeholder=Comment..>' +
            '<button data-postId="'+i+'" class="postComment">Post</button></div>');

        $('.glyphicon-remove').click(function() {
            var postId = $(this).parent().attr('data-postId');
            console.log(postId);
            aPosts.splice(i, 1);

        });
    }
}
```

When I console log "postId" it tells me that I am at least clicking the right post, but it wont delete it from localStorage.

Comment: So anyone can delete any post if they start messing with the IDs?

Comment: It's personal project, so yeah anyone can delete posts.

Comment: If you change `aPosts.splice(i, 1);` to `aPosts.splice(parseInt(postId), 1);` does that help? I would also take the click event definition out of the for loop.

Comment: Hi @mccannf - Thank you for the suggestion but it's not working unfortunately.

Comment: You are attaching click handlers every time in the foreach. Take it out of the foreach. And you need to manually tell jQuery to `.remove()` the icon's parent that was clicked.

Comment: I just edit my comment to let know that I want to remove it from my localStorage.

Comment: You use `localStorage.removeItem(<key to data>);` to remove items from localStorage...